# decomposing a string into small pieces with sscanf and bracket use

Tags: c, scanf, brackets

I must be missing something very simple but I have no clues.
After running this:

```
int main() {
   char requete[] = {"205 7.3 data data\n"};
   char codeUserReq[9];
   char choixReq[3];
   char donneeReq[200];

   memset(codeUserReq, 0, 5);
   memset(choixReq, 0, 3);
   memset(donneeReq, 0, 200);

   sscanf(requete, "%s %s %[^\n]", codeUserReq, choixReq, donneeReq);
   printf("codeuser %s \n",codeUserReq);
   printf("choix %s \n",choixReq);
   printf("donnee %s \n",donneeReq);
```

I expect the result to be :

```
codeuser 205
choix 7.3
donnee data data
```

Instead, it is:

```
codeuser
choix 7.3
donnee data data
```

On ubuntu this code works, but not on debian.

The first string is not properly read.

Comment: You overflow `choixReq` by writing "7.3" to it, so your code has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overflow `choixReq` by writing "7.3" to it (since that's `'7', '.', '3', '\0'`, four characters).

If I change `choixReq` to hold 4 characters instead, I get the correct output:

```
codeuser 205
choix 7.3
donnee data data
```

Comment: god bless you !!
i couldn't figure why for days...
mind you explaining me why the overflow of ```choixReq``` comme to disturb ```codeUser``` ??
and why this work on ubuntu and not on debian ?

Comment: @idiocrate Undefined behavior means *anything can happen*. All bets are off.

Comment: i this is the first case of Undefined behavior that blew my mind. Again thanks for resolving my stupid mistake.